# Azure Pipelines Options Build Number: Does $(Rev:r) increment on every build?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) states that "When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one".

However, you can see below that even though something *did* change, it still incremented.

[image: Build Versions]

[image: Build number format]

Does anyone know what the actual behavior is when using `$(Rev:r)` in the build number?

Comment: `$(Rev:r)` pays attention to whether the variable on the left has changed, and does not detect the entire Build number. In addition, the automatic increment is placed at the end of the Build number instead of in the middle. So, I agree with Alex P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `build number format` specified like this:

```
1.$(Rev:r).$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)
```

You do consequent builds. Everything on the left side from `$(Rev:r)` stays constant as you hard coded the prefix `1.`. The right side of `$(Rev:r)` doesn't matter here. Hence, your `$(Rev:r)` keeps incrementing on 1, like this:

```
1.1.2010 // first build on tenth day of 2020
1.2.2010 // second build, same day
1.3.2115 // third build on fifteenth day of 2021
```

Now if you change your format to

```
1.$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(Rev:r)
```

you will end up with this behavior

```
1.2010.1 // first build on tenth day of 2020
1.2010.2 // second build, same day
1.2115.1 // third build on fifteenth day of 2021
```

Comment: Ah, so it evaluates it in a left-right manner. Thank you!